# Add different meta box based on taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, metabox

i created a plugin with a  custom post type.

I added a new custom taxonomy also under that post type .

How can i add the meta boxes based on different taxonomy.

```
if( is_object_in_term('', 'name of the taxonomy ','term_name' ) ) {


add_action( 'admin_init', 'add meta box method name' );
```

But that did not work

Comment: Can you explain why you need to do this? There may be better ways of solving your original issue

Comment: i am making a video gallery  with playlist. default page will add , edit option with list videos  .I use Reusable Custom WordPress Meta Boxes for add video screen .  I added a new  taxonomy for playlist . i want different screen for the playlist . how can i do that